# Secondary password file creation and reset

Tags: command-line, linux-kernel, password, command, authentication

Is there any way to reset all passwords previously created when the secondary password file is enabled for the first time to ensure higher-level protection ?.

Comment: Can you give more details about this secondary password file? is it `/etc/shadow` or are you talking about something else?

Comment: Yes /etc/shadow only.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to expire all user accounts with a loop using the `passwd` command, forcing them to change their password on next login. Avoid this on system accounts. Eg, user accounts on Linux Debian based systems start at uid 1000. Most system accounts have a disabled password anyway.

From [`man passwd`](https://manpages.debian.org/passwd.1.en.html#OPTIONS):

> -e, --expire
>   Immediately expire an account's password. This in effect can force a user to change his/her password at the user's next
>   login.

There are other related options to take care about (like `-i, --inactive` which might later disable such accounts).

Use a loop iterating on users (eg using contents of `/etc/passwd` or more generic using [`getent passwd [someuser]`](https://manpages.debian.org/getent.1.en.html)